# Using MySQL with visual studio and changing the connection at runtime

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio-2010, odbc

I use something like this for my application

```
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;" + 
                                          "Database=myDataBase;" + 
                                          "Uid=myUsername;" + 
                                          "Pwd=myPassword;");
```

And this changes everytime because we deploy databases with our application.
It works fine. I type in `using(new connection(cnn)){ query... }` and go. 
And I've got it working with a dataset using a connection defined in the windows ODBC datasouce administrator. 
But I'm curious, is there a way to use visual studio's dataset items using the my local test db and then change the connection of the dataset at runtime? Even better, can I use c# to programmatically add the ODBC data source at runtime?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't point the ODBC connection at your test database, and then have an ODBC connection with the same name pointed at the production database later?

Comment: And there is any reason to use an ODBC data source when you could store your connectionstring in the config of your application? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have in the past used the ODBC connection with the same name for the production database. I just don't like it because it's an extra step at install, which is why I was wondering if it was possible to programmatically define this.

Comment: Usually the connectionstring is stored in the config file of the application where it could easily changed when you deploy your application (through installers or manually if needed)

Comment: Steve, I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly, but to connect to the MySQL db using a connection string, ive always had to type 'MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)' - I assumed there was some limitation for MySQL because I just cant seem to get MySQL to work with a connection string in visual studio, using data connections in the server explorer window.

Comment: I can't find any problem with that approach. On the contrary, this is the standard way to do it. The string `connectionString` should be read from your config file using the ConfigurationManager. Which kind of application are we talking about here? ASP.NET, WinForms ?

Comment: WinForms. Using visual studio 2010. I can set up the data connection using server name, username, password and if I check the properties  it shows the correct conectionstring, but it's read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a connection string is loaded from the application exe.config file present in the same folder of the application. This connection string could be defined using the Settings tab in the project properties.

- Right click on Properties of your project
- Select the Settings tab (confirm the creation if you have no
  settings)
- Click on the ComboBox in the column type and select Connection String
- Give a symbolic name to your connection
- Type the connection string in the Value column (Examples at
  [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/))

Now in your project files you should have the file app.config (that becomes yourapp.exe.config) where there is a section like this

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppConnection"
      connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDB;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration
```

At this point you read it in the program using

```
  string conString = ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["MyAppConnection"]
                        .ConnectionString;
```

Instead in a dynamic situation where you want to build yourself the connection string during runtime (from user inputs, your own configuration files and so on) then you could leverage the functionality of the class MySqlConnectionStringBuilder

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
msb.Server = "localhost";
msb.Port = 3306;
msb.UserID = "root";
msb.Password = "xxx";
msb.Database = "test";
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(msb.ConnectionString);
cnn.Open();
```

Of course, these literal values could be substituted by your own variables. 
The documentation of this class is surprising difficult to find. The best docs are the one of the [Sql Server equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is interesting that you could read a static connection string from your config file and then change only the property needed.

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager
                  .ConnectionStrings["MyAppConnection"]
                  .ConnectionString;
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder msb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
msb.Database = "AnotherDB";
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(msb.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: But my issue is it is read only. I get what you said about changing it manually or at install, because I can just edit the config file. But how do I set it so the serveraddress, for example, to be set to a variable. (I currently store it as a string in the config file and edit it using `properties.settings.default.serveraddress = "...";`

Comment: Ok so it is a dynamic situation. Then there is the MySqlConnectionStringBuilder class to the rescue. I write an example above

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

Application connection string cannot be changed at runtime.
User settings can be changed.

Assuming you are using  an application setting-property named "MyConnectionString" which holds the connection string for the entire application.
On your main Program class create a global string:

`internal static string Prconnstring;`

Create and save this `settings.cs` file:

```
namespace MYSOLUTIONORPROJECTNAME.Properties
{
    // (Not sure where I found this solution some time ago)
    // This class allows you to handle specific events on the settings class:
    //  The SettingChanging event is raised before a setting's value is changed.
    //  The PropertyChanged event is raised after a setting's value is changed.
    //  The SettingsLoaded event is raised after the setting values are loaded.
    //  The SettingsSaving event is raised before the setting values are saved.
    internal sealed partial class Settings
    {

        public Settings()
        {
            // // To add event handlers for saving and changing settings, uncomment the lines below:
            //
            // this.SettingChanging += this.SettingChangingEventHandler;
            //
            // this.SettingsSaving += this.SettingsSavingEventHandler;
            //
        }

        private void SettingChangingEventHandler(object sender, System.Configuration.SettingChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add code to handle the SettingChangingEvent event here.
        }

        private void SettingsSavingEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add code to handle the SettingsSaving event here.
        }

        public override object this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (propertyName == "MyConnectionString")
                {
                    return Program.Prconnstring;
                }
                else
                {
                    return base[propertyName];
                }
            }
            set
            {
                base[propertyName] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before calling-opening any object that uses the connection string (examples include Forms that use datasets or other classes that use datasets created on the development enviroment) create your new connection string by any means you think. (*Example: You might want to use as user name in the connection string the current user. Create the connection string using the info provided form the environment.*)

Program.Prconnstring = thenewruntimeconnectionstring.

Now whenever the application tries to get `MyConnectionString` (which is hardcoded in the `myapplicationname.config` and cannot be changed) instead gets the new `thenewruntimeconnectionstring` you provided to `Program.Prconnstring`.

Be aware that the development connection string will be available-visible to final user, since it is just a text file. If you do not want this, you can change that file (will be a file named NAMEOFMYAPPLICATION.exe.config) during deployment, since the connection string hardcoded there, will be of no use for the running app. Do not delete it, just change.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just add `My.Settings("MyConnectionString") ="[your new connection string]"` to your Entry point's Load or New sub. This changes which db your datasource is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string will be stored in your App.config (or c# equivalent). Say it's called `MyConnectionString`. Just add `My.Settings("MyConnectionString")="[your new connection string]"` to your entry point to change to database binding at runtime. E.g:

```vb
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    My.Settings("MyConnectionString") = "server=remotedb.uk;user id=MainUser;password=2jdi38edhnche73g;database=mainDb;persistsecurityinfo=True;allowuservariables=True;defaultcommandtimeout=480;characterset=utf8mb4"

End Sub
```